# How to simulate modification of ERC20 token balance using Ethereum State Override?

Tags: ethereum

I am attempting to simulate the modification of an ERC20 token balance using Ethereum’s State Override feature. I have injected the token contract code into the EVM and used State Override to modify the balance of a target account. However, the result of querying the balance of the target account always returns 0, no matter how I adjust my code.

I have tried various methods, including using different fake code, modifying different state variables, etc. However, the result is always incorrect.

I would like to know where I am going wrong, or if there is another way to use State Override to simulate the modification of an ERC20 token balance?

I have tried with following code with change USDT balance, but not work:

```
(async () => {
    const Web3 = require('web3');
    const web3 = new Web3('http://192.168.50.159:7546'); 

    const targetAddress = '0xb7BF3e961645b8ebB75A622A07983335B61cf5c0'; // replace with the target account address
    const usdtContractAddress = '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'; //  USDT contract address
    const fakeUsdtCode = '0x606060405260008054600160a060020a03191673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff9091169150506103c3806100516000396000f3';

    const fakeUsdtBalance = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff'; // set the fake USDT balance to 255

    const result = await web3.eth.call({
        to: usdtContractAddress,
        data: '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000' + targetAddress.substring(2), // USDT balanceOf() function
        stateOverride: {
            account: targetAddress,
            code: fakeUsdtCode,
            storage: {
                [web3.utils.sha3('balances(' + targetAddress + ')')]: fakeUsdtBalance
            }
        }
    });

    console.log('USDT balance of ' + targetAddress + ': ' + web3.utils.hexToNumberString(result));
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ##### `web3.eth.call` doesn't support state override parameters.

The argument formatter of `eth_call` ignores the `stateOverride` field. You can extend `web3.eth` and call the RPC method manually:

```js
web3.eth.extend({
    methods: [
        {
            name: 'callWithState',
            call: 'eth_call',
            params: 3,
        }
    ]
});
```

2. ##### `eth_call` state override json structure is not valid, should be:

```js
const stateOverride = {
    [usdtContractAddress]: {
        stateDiff: {
            [mappingSlot]: fakeUsdtBalance,
        }
    }
}
```

3. ##### Storage key is wrong.

You should take the slot number into consideration. You calculate it from the source code: https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code The `balances` state variable has the slot number - `2`. *(I've written an article about slots and storage [simple-deep-dive-into-evm-storage](https://dev.kit.eco/ethereum-simple-deep-dive-into-evm-storage))*

The correct slot calculation would be:

```js
let mValue = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters (['address', 'uint256'], [targetAddress, 2]);
let mSlot = web3.utils.keccak256(mValue)
```

4. ##### Something wrong with your overridden bytecode.

Geth throws an exception: `stack underflow (2 <=> 3)`

---

To summarize the code:

```js
web3.eth.extend({
  methods: [
    {
      name: 'callWithState',
      call: 'eth_call',
      params: 3,
    }
  ]
});

const targetAddress = '0xb7BF3e961645b8ebB75A622A07983335B61cf5c0';
const usdtContractAddress = '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7';
const fakeUsdtCode = '0x606060405260008054600160a060020a03191673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff9091169150506103c3806100516000396000f3';

const fakeUsdtBalance = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff';

const mValue = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['address', 'uint256'], [targetAddress, 2]);
const mSlot = web3.utils.keccak256(mValue)

const callParams = {
  to: usdtContractAddress,
  data: '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000' + targetAddress.substring(2),
};
const stateDiff = {
  [usdtContractAddress]: {
    //code: fakeUsdtCode,
    stateDiff: {
      [mSlot]: fakeUsdtBalance,
    },
  }
};

const result = await web3.eth.callWithState(callParams, 'latest', stateDiff);
console.log(`USDT balance: ${result}`);
//>  USDT balance: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff
```

Comment: Nice article. I’m trying to calculate balances by tallying up transfer events. I’m seeing quite some fake transfer events on certain contracts where no underlying state is changed resulting in negative balances etc. I was hoping to be able to calculate balances properly by checking if a transfer did in fact result in a state change (it should be possible to find the state location knowing the from and to address and assuming unknown the ‘balance’ mapping. Seems like an awful lot of work though. Any other way to be sure?

Comment: This is similar to how we dump the contract's storage in [0xweb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/0xweb). 1. Get all mapping keys, for example `from` and `to` are the balances keys. 2. Load storage slots with batch call to get all balance amounts.

Comment: How do you know when to look for updated state? I mean, state can be changed without an event going out, so events can be guiding here. So I guess what I’m asking is: how do you know when to look for state changes?

Comment: I don't. The past log events are just to get all the possible keys to fetch the values later from the mapping. For well-designed contracts, this works well, but if the mapping is modified without emitting the log, then you would need to load traces for every transaction to get the state modifications, but the performance of such indexing is very poor.